# Android's addJavascriptInterface equivalent in iOS

Tags: android, ios, uiwebview, webview, android-webview

As you may know, Android's WebView has a method named `addJavascriptInterface()` which imports an Android JAVA object to Javascript context.

the question is, Is there any equivalent of it on iOS?

Answer (score 5):

UIWebView on iOS doesn't have methods to add interface to DOM.
But you still can talk to your code from javascript assigning something to `window.location` and handling that request in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is really old, but it seems that there is a better way to do it now with a `WKWebView`.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37373745/1417922