# Does UIWebView on iOS have methods to add interface to DOM?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

For android there is a method named `addJavascriptInterface()` which imports an Android JAVA object to Javascript context.  Is there any equivalent of it on **iOS**?
I have gone through some of the similar questions :
[androids-addjavascriptinterface-equivalent-in-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103159/androids-addjavascriptinterface-equivalent-in-ios)
[calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications/)
But could not find a proper solution to my question .

```
function initiateAddCall(){
        var locus = reader.getPlace().getLocus();
        RoomHelper.postReaderLocus(JSON.stringify(locus));
}
```

`RoomHelper` is the javascript handler which am using . Is there any way i can implement this (**Register a javascript handler/interface in UIWebView iOS**) in `UIWebView` **iOS** .

Comment: Hope you find a solution for this . Am also stuck with same interface/handler problem .

Answer (score 8):

I just used [EasyJSWebView](https://github.com/dukeland/EasyJSWebView) and worked pretty well.
There are others solutions like [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) but EasyJSWebView was easier to use.

```
RoomHelper *roomHelper = [RoomHelper new];
[self.myWebView addJavascriptInterfaces:interface WithName:@"RoomHelper"];
[self.myWebView injectJS:webView];
```

in javascript you call:

```
RoomHelper.test()
```

and in RoomHelper you implement a method called test

RoomHelper.h :

```
@interface RoomHelper : NSObject

- (void) test;

@end
```

Comment: can you please explain me how i can exactly get the same working for : function initiateAddCall(){
        var locus = reader.getPlace().getLocus();
        RoomHelper.postReaderLocus(JSON.stringify(locus));
} . I have check easyJSWebView but i failed to implement this in my project . RoomHelper is my handler .

Comment: Also when i used EasyJSWebView my app crashes at addjavascriptinterface:

Comment: What is the message log when it crashes?

Comment: [UIWebView addJavascriptInterfaces:WithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff203091c70 this is the error which am getting .

Comment: Are you using Xib or Storyboard? Because you need to change the class of  the UIWebview to EasyJSWebView in the viewcontroller and in the attribute inspector of Xib or Storybord

Comment: Ok i have changed the class now . Now its working . libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap: but am getting this warning now .

Comment: @RyniereSilva  can someone tell me how should i call the js function initiateAddCall() ??

Answer (score 1):

Had to use this for a native app project where i was using D3.JS to show the graphs. Used the below code to call the JS function

```
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"showLegendGraphsFromDevice('%@',%d)",sectionName, position];
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

Here

```
function showLegendGraphsFromDevice(name, position)
```

is the JS function

Key here is creating the correct JS string with the needed quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavascriptCore to implement `addJavascriptInterface`.

- https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/javascriptcore-example/
- http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/