# UIWebView and JavaScriptInterface in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

How can I to create the JavascriptInterface channel from my web site to my UIWebView?

Example in Android:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

And from this JavascriptInterface I would like to draw the methods, as for example:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView)
```

or

```
myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For WKWebView: source [here](http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift)

JavaScript

```
function callNativeApp () {
    try {
            webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
    } catch(err) {
            console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
    }
}
```

Swift

```
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView? = nil

    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "callbackHandler")
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        self.webView = WKWebView( frame: self.containerView!.bounds, configuration: config)
        self.view = self.webView

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //I use the file html in local
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html") 
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)

    }

    func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {// edit: changed fun to func
        if (message.name == "callbackHandler"){
            print("\(message.body)")
        }
    }

}
```

For UIWebView: source [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daaGaZp7ElY)

JavaScript in HTML

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(){
            $(window).load(function(){

               $('.clickMe').on('click', function(){
                   window.location = "foobar://fizz?Hello_from_javaScript";
               });
            });
         })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Web: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        Web.delegate = self
        Web.loadRequest(req)
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if request.URL?.query != nil {
            print("\(request.URL!.query!)")
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: How to load local html file inside WKWebView?

Comment: I am having error in js. e.g: **webkit is undefined**. What to do?

Comment: @iPeter did u import the Webkit?? `import WebKit` and add the library `WebKit.framework` to your Build Phase.

Comment: Could you please tell me where you added the "Android" keyword that added in the webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
I want to add this keyword in my iOS app. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: has anyone ever found another way except the using postMessage(), calling Swift methods directly from Swift like iosListener.someMethod(), where some method for example returns a string, and iOSListener is name of userContentController, as we use it for postMessage() ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick example:

1. Register a URL Scheme such as `foobar` in Xcode
2. Handle this URL Scheme in your web view

   ```
   func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
       if request.URL?.query?.containsString("show_activity_indicator=true") {
           myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, call this from your JavaScript

   ```
   // Show your activity indicator from JavaScript.
   window.location = "foobar://fizz?show_activity_indicator=true"
   ```

**Note**: See [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851630/javascript-synchronous-native-communication-to-wkwebview) for more information on web view communication in iOS.