# display server generated image in PWA using JavaScript in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, progressive-web-apps

Facing issue in PWA.
I am trying to display image in WKWebview in iOS using HTML, Javascript.

Example: 
I have added below file in xCode project and configuring with WKWebview.

in .html

```
<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/klipfolio/image/upload/v1500283193/pic_bulboff_to4zaq.png"  height="180">
    <p>Click the lightbulb to turn on/off the light</p>
```

in .js file (JavaScript)

```
window.changeImage = function() {
    element=document.getElementById('myimage');
    if (element.src.match("bulbon")) {
        element.src="http://res.cloudinary.com/klipfolio/image/upload/v1500283193/pic_bulboff_to4zaq.png";
    }
    else { element.src="http://res.cloudinary.com/klipfolio/image/upload/v1500283189/pic_bulbon_tvpcg5.png";
    }
}
```

But, not displaying image in Webview. showing white box only..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect HTTP is not allowed in your info.plist. you might want to try it with HTTPS as the cloudinary.com has a valid https certificate

Comment: Try loading WKWebView with following url https://jsfiddle.net/Lz9go1q0/1/

Comment: @SahilManchandaThanks Sahil. After using https also it is not working in WKWebview

Comment: I'm glad this works for you.

Comment: @SahilManchanda I'm not able to update the image on click event

Comment: you also need to change the source with https in js file too.

Comment: @SahilManchanda Yes done that too..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198158/discussion-between-ruchira-more-and-sahil-manchanda).

Comment: @SahilManchanda Please help in this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134733/how-to-inject-js-file-to-interact-with-pwa-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to HTTP resources. By default HTTP is disabled. There are two ways you can make it work.

A) By enabling HTTP (Discouraged)

B) By using a valid SSL

Since the image resource already has a valid SSL certificate, changing from HTTP to HTTPS will do the trick.